# Horizontal expandable uiscrollview or uitableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

[image: State when non-expanded <code>uiscrollview</code>]

[image: State when expanded <code>uiscrollview</code>]

I want to create an expandable `uiscrollview` like the images shown above.
I've tried to search with keywords but cannot find any example similar to what I want to achieve.

I wonder if I should use `uiscrollview` or `uitableview`?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Desdenova Thanks but how can I make it expandable similar to the images shown above?

Comment: This will help http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Why not use a collection view?

Comment: @Fogmeister maybe because you want to target iOS5 too?

Comment: That would be a valid reason but no mention of that is made in the question. Plus with over 90% of devices on iOS 6 it would only add a very small (and diminishing) number of people to the user base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a UITableView then rotate it 90 degrees counter clock wise and it will work like a charm.

Just create a UITableView subclass (i.r. HorizontalUITableView) and in the initWithFrame, rotate the view 90 degrees:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2.0);
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

You will also need to subclass your UITableViewCell's and rotate them 90 degrees too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm interpreting your images correctly, I'd suggest you first create a UIView subclass that represents one of those stacks. It will need to manage a list of items/images, and be able to animate between the expanded/collapsed modes. Then create a UIScrollView subclass to manage a set of these stacks, and have it animate the layout of the stacks based on the current size of each stack as they expand/collapse.